# Ruby upgrade version and code compatibility checker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Is there a way to upgrade the underlying Ruby version of a rails project and be certain there are no breaking changes within the code? I use rvm to maintain my Ruby environment and I know I can simply create a new environment and go from there but that would involve testing the entire application.

For example, my Gemfile specifies the following:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'rake'
```

If I were to upgrade to Ruby 2.4 is there any way to check my code to see if there are any breaking changes between versions?

Comment: Do you have test in your project?

Comment: I wouldn't advise going to 2.4 directly from 2.0. Move up by 1 minor version at a time.

Comment: @inye I do but there's nowhere close to complete coverage.

Comment: @emaillenin I'm fine doing that but I'd still was wondering if there's a script that can traverse my code searching for potential issues.

Comment: Before upgrading to ruby/rails you have to have full test coverage. There is not other way to ensure/check if nothing is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you are using `bundler` you can do a `bundle update` and it will update all the gems to the latest compatible versions. You can then do a `bundle clean` it will remove unused gems and finally using rvm you can update versions and test functionality.